# Is it possible to run multiple versions of the same webservice?

Tags: web-services, iis, .net-1.1

**[RUN DOWN]**

- I am required to call on a webservice with version information embedded in the webservice name.
  EG. webserviceV1
- When I generate a proxy class from the wsdl the webservice name is used to as the class name.
  I am using the wsdl.exe tool.
- I can foresee that a new version of the webservice would result in my code base having to support 2 sets of proxy classes. Or for the code that use the existing proxy classes to be renamed.

**[MY QUESTION]**

- I would like to propose a solution to the provider that would allow them to provide multiple versions of the webservice as it is early on in the project.
- I was advised that a possible solution would be to provide the webservice via different ports.
  However having tried myself I don't know if that is even possible via IIS.
- Is it possible to run multiple versions of a webservice at the same time on the same machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is possible. Instead of appending version numbers to webservice classes, place them in separate virtual directories:

```
http://host/services/1.0/service.asmx
http://host/services/1.3/service.asmx
http://host/services/2.0/service.asmx
```

You will then have to devise a versioning scheme (use branches properly; see [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control) for some thoughts on that) to support all versions of service simultaneously.

As for the code, you can try abstracting differences between service versions behind a common interface (think `AbstractService`) and then use it as a base for version-specific implementations (`ServiceV1_3`).

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_ruRU317RU317&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=versioning+web+services) gives pretty nice results for this exact topic.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Will attempt to learn how to do this.